# How to dynamically add active class on wordpress category pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Am new to wordpress development and I want to add an active class on my category pages. I also need the `All Article` to have the active class by default on load. Here's my code.

```
<p>
  <?php
    global $wp;
    $catURI = basename(home_url( $wp->request ));
    $activeURI = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $categories = get_categories(); ?>
      Blog categories: <a href=" <?php echo site_url(); ?>" class="cat-link <?php if ($activePage == $activeURI) echo 'active'; ?>">All Articles</a>
      <?php foreach($categories as $category) { 
        echo $catURI == $activeURI 
         ? '<a class="cat-link active" href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>'
         : '<a class="cat-link" href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
      }
  ?>
</p>
```

This however does not add the active class to the `All Articles` link and adds it to all the other `category links` when I click on one of them.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

This could sound like a repetition, but most of the solutions I've gotten seem not to solve my challenge.

Comment: If possible, try to use [`wp_list_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference%2Ffunctions%2Fwp_list_categories%2F/) because it does all of this for you, with many configurable options. If there's a minor tweak to the HTML that it doesn't support, you can also attack that using the [filter of the same name](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_list_categories/).

Comment: But that will not list the `All Categories` link on top of the other categories, will it?

Comment: Yes, if you read through the options, and there are a lot of them, one is `show_option_all` which you can set to the text that you want to display.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas. Am trying to change from the default list to span by using `style`, but this removes all classes and the default `show_option_all`. Is there a way to achieve this or must I have to work with lists? Also how do I give the `show_option_all` a default `active` class on load?

Comment: You should be able to do the basics of what you are talking about in CSS. Unless you are doing something very, very specific, you should be able to turn the bullets off on the `<li>` tags, make them inline-block and tweak some margins/padding, effectively making them `<span>` tags. For the default active class on the "all" item. take a look at the default classes on the body tag. If your taxonomy is `category` the selector `body:not(.category) .cat-item-all{}` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance. Maybe you should post it as an answer so I mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: unfortunately I don't have time to work up a more fleshed out example for a good answer, so I'm totally fine with you posting what you built and accepting it as the answer, and I'd gladly up-vote it, too.

Comment: Glad it worked! WordPress (and any complex system, really) can be frustrating until you learn the hundreds of helper functions. After all these years I still learn about functions that have been around for many years, too.

Comment: That's for sure. And getting to understand the codex documentation is also a skill. Am working n a different project and require to style the `title_li` (give it a background-color). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @ChrisHaas, I was able to get a workaround. This is the code that I finally used, and styled it accordingly.

```
<?php
  wp_list_categories(array(
  'show_option_all' => 'All Articles',
  'class' => 'post-category flex',
  'title_li' => 'Blog categories:'
  )); 
?>
```